# ASP.NET Using DB-Context in _layout.cshtml

Tags: asp.net, layout, razor-pages

I'm trying to access the database context from _layout.cshtml to select notifications and display them in a [dropdown box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcKhJ.png).

Can anyone tell me how to get the context in layout? I'm using razor-pages.

Answer (score 1):

Look into ViewComponents. They are perfect candiates for this task. You can hookup to a db and return the data to your dropdown component then you can add them to your layout page like this.

@await Component.InvokeAsync("NotificationList", new { maxPriority = 2, isDone = true })

or like a tag helper

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-2.1